# Why connection.getResponseCode() fails outside of doInBackground()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

```
    public String urltobody(String createdurl){ 
            URL url = new URL (createdurl); 
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();//fails here
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                String content = convertInputStream(is, "UTF-8"); 
                is.close();
                return content;
            }
    }
```

The above function works if I call it inside of doInBackground but does not workin onPostExecute. I really need to call this function independent to pre, background, post prdocedure.

This is my class definition `private class FetchTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String>`

Please let me know if you can help me with one of the below questions.

Do you know how I can call my function outside of doInbackground?

Do you know what happens when I call new FetchTask().execute()?

Any other solution?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that [doInBackground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) is run in a **background thread** while [onPreExectute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) [onPostExecute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) are run in the **UI-thread**.

==> Url Connections should *not be done from UI thread*, (because it may freeze the UI while it is loading) that is why Android throws an NetworkOnMainThreadException whenever you try to do that.

==> This is the reason why you should establish network connections only asynchronously from the background thread not UI thread. That is why it only works in doInBackground.

Comment: Thank you... so should I go back to doInbackground and do play with global variables and do what I want to do?

Comment: Everything that involves establishing network connections or other things that are potentially time-consuming should go into the background thread. The UI thread should be only updating the UI

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
private class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
```

instead of

```
private class FetchTask extenends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String>
```

May be solve your problem.

also for example for your understanding

```
private class ResponseLocDepts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                URL url = new URL (createdurl); 
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();//fails here
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            String content = convertInputStream(is, "UTF-8"); 
            is.close();
            return true;
        }
       else
        {
         return false;
         }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
                // somethings

        }

    }
```

String content should be globally diclare. 
Please try it.

Comment: the original code is extends, I edited the question. Thank you

Comment: I did not get it. Why changing String to Boolean will solve the problem that is described in the question?